# What is the advantage of structuring collections with userID as document keys vs as documents with the userID attribute?

Tags: nosql, google-cloud-firestore

Specifically for Firestore, why would one structure their root-collections as userId documents that contains a userPosts sub-collection that holds each user's posts. Why wouldn't one just hold the posts in the root collection and query-filter by userId?

For example, many StackOverflow Q/As about structuring data suggests to have something like this:

```
'users':{
  'user1@gmail.com': {
    'username': 'user1'
  }
},
'posts':{
  'user1@gmail.com': {
    'userPosts':{
      'post1': {
         'content': 'post1 content'
       },
      'post2': {
         'content': 'post2 content'
       },
    }
  }
}
```

where 'users' and 'posts' are collections and 'userPosts' is a sub-collection and the query is:

`db.collection('posts').doc('user1@gmail.com').collection('userPosts').get()`

What is the advantage of organizing the 'posts' collections by userId (email in this case) and userPosts rather than keeping a collection full of notes and querying by matching userId with the post's userId, like so:

```
'users':{
  'user1@gmail.com': {
    'username': 'user1'
  }
},
'posts':{
  'post1': {
     'userId': 'user1@gmail.com',
     'content': 'post1 content'
   },
  'post2': {
     'userId': 'user1@gmail.com',
     'content': 'post2 content'
   },
}
```

where the query is:

`db.collection('posts').where('userId', '==', 'user1@gmail.com')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with nosql type databases, all decisions about data structure should be based on the queries you intend to perform.  Without knowing your queries, a certain structure may not actually meet all the requirements of your app.  This is why data is often duplicated in nosql databases - to suit queries that may not be possible otherwise.

In your example, for the *one use case* that you've provided, there is no real advantage to structuring the data either way.  The advantage to choosing one or the other is more likely based on other queries that you might want to perform.

For example, if you wanted to construct some query across all posts for all users, it is (currently) not possible with your first structure.

There may also be the issue of security rules.  Some database structures are easier to protect with some security rules.  But again, it depends on the requirements for your rules.

Bottom line is that the advantageous structure is the one that meets all the needs of all your queries and rules.  But a single structure may not meet all your needs, and you may end up keeping two or more in sync.